# wpf how to run method in interactions.triggers

Tags: c#, wpf

How can i run a method from my code in the Interactions.trigger (interactivity) ?

I have code of

```
       <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="HandleShowMessage"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

which is HandleShowMessage() is a method from the code behind.
I tried that code but its not working

Comment: You can use Command option for triggering

Comment: Please post the full call and the code behind.

Comment: @Md.AbdulAlim what is the sample code for that?

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII Its just a code behind for HandleShowMessage() and do something

Answer (score 0):

You can binding by command like

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <ei:CallMethodAction Command="{Binding DataContext.HandleShowMessage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type expenses:MainWindow}}}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```